# Name that entity

Tags: riddle

I dont know how this one might go down, but no chance of finding out if not asked

Name the entity being described

> Me and my family made in the UK
>   the lesser of 3 my siblings say
>   Kept together unwanted
>   in darkness till sorted
>   Our absence will give you leeway.

See what you think, if theres no interest ill assume my career is over here.

> The greatest of we
>  alone has 99 more than me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My guess at this one is... **the penny**

Comment: Looks like it matches all the clues, good job.

Comment: Give that man a penny.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to edit this answer to explain how you reached this conclusion given the information in the question?

Answer (score 4):

The entity being described is

> The British Government
>  Which is composed of three parts: "Her Majesty Queen Elizabeth the Second, by the Grace of God, of the United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland and of Her other Realms and Territories Queen, Head of the Commonwealth, Defender of the Faith." who is the figurative head of Her Majesty's Government, plus Parliament which is divided into the House of Lords and the House of Commons.
>  The House of Commons is the lesser of the 3.
>  Kept together unwanted, because let's face it, who wants these clowns in parliament?
>  In darkness till sorted, because honestly, is there any light and truth in Parliament until the Queen signs off on something with her rubber stamp?
>  Our absence will give you leeway, because without the House of Commons there will be no new laws and you will have more leeway in what you are allowed to do.

Comment: That's what I thought. Thanks for typing it all.

Comment: Great answer and well thought out, seems to fit aswell so yes it could be a possible right answer, but it was not the one I originally had in mind. Though yours seems more interesting and politically charged.